Cannot import any org.bukkit libs
I am making a spigot mod with using a spigot jar and running that and I cannot import anything from org.bukkit.
My plugin is supposed to give players random hearts when they join for the first time.
My code is:
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import java.util.Random;

public class RandomHeartsPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        int randomHearts = generateRandomHearts();
        player.setHealth(randomHearts);
        player.sendMessage("You have been given " + randomHearts + " extra hearts!");
    }

    private int generateRandomHearts() {
        Random random = new Random();
        // Generating a random number between 0 and 20 (inclusive)
        return random.nextInt(21);
    }
}

and I run it with the command:
javac plugins/RandomHeartsPlugin.java -cp bundler/libaries

I tried using -cp wiht other things but I still can't compile it, I get:
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:3: error: package org.bukkit.entity does not exist
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
                        ^
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:4: error: package org.bukkit.event does not exist
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
                       ^
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:5: error: package org.bukkit.event does not exist
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
                       ^
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:6: error: package org.bukkit.event.player does not exist
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
                              ^
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
                             ^
  symbol:   class JavaPlugin
  location: package org.bukkit.plugin.java
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class RandomHeartsPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
                                        ^
  symbol: class JavaPlugin
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class RandomHeartsPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
                                                              ^
  symbol: class Listener
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class PlayerJoinEvent
  location: class RandomHeartsPlugin
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    @EventHandler
     ^
  symbol:   class EventHandler
  location: class RandomHeartsPlugin
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:13: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        ^
  symbol:   method getServer()
  location: class RandomHeartsPlugin
plugins\RandomHeartsPlugin.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        ^
  symbol:   class Player
  location: class RandomHeartsPlugin
12 errors


Did you tried to use something like gradle or maven that will manage the build for you ?

no how do i use that?

You can find tutorial here or here

what about for maven

It's here or here. In general, search in google to how to setup according to your ide (eclipse, intellij etc)

Turns out in itelliJ the UI hid it from me
